# Doxygen - Inherit documentation for overwritten signals/slots

Tags: qt, overriding, doxygen, signals-slots

I am creating my documentation using doxygen and enabled the `INHERIT_DOCS` option. This works fine for normal methods. The documenation of the base class will apear in the class the re-implements the method.

However, if I do the same for signals or slots, doxygen won't inherit the doc, the members appear but stay undocumented.

Am I missing something or is that a bug? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note: You usually don't reimplement signals, do you?

Comment: No, I do know that signals cannot be overridden. Im using this to create a "pure virtual" signal that has to be implemented using "final". it's part of an interface for plugins.

Comment: Can you, please, add an example with source code?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work out-of-the-box in Doxygen 1.8.15.

I was surprised to see a "Signals inherited from " section in my docs, since I didn't specify anything in the comments, but there it is all the same.